# Part of a website only accessible to users

Tags: users

Is it possible to restrict a part of a website to craft user-groups?

For instance if I want show an internal Blog to members-only.

And is it possible to moderate user registrations? So when somebody registers an Admin has to approve it first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is! You can use the `requirePermission` tag:

```
{% requirePermission "yourPermission" %}
```

See the full documentation [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/requirepermission). Keep in mind this list as built in permissions but you can also add custom permissions through a plugin should you require it.

As far the second question, I'm not 100% sure but I believe you can set "enabled" to "false" when creating a registration form. See further details [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form).

Update: You can also use [isInGroup](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usermodel#isInGroup)

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into it. Never had anything to do with user based stuff.